# Get original To & From phone numbers redirected to Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

How do I capture the original TO & FROM phone numbers redirected from a carrier TO Twilio and then trigger a webhook?

Call > Carrier_ConditionalForwarding_MissedCall > Twilio?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure on how this works, but in the webhook request that Twilio makes to your application, it can [send the parameter `ForwardedFrom`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#request-parameters) which is described like this:

> This parameter is set only when Twilio receives a forwarded call, but its value depends on the caller's carrier including information when forwarding.
>
> Not all carriers support passing this information.

As far as I can tell, that is all the information you can get about an incoming call. My assumption is that the original `From` number remains the same and the `ForwardedFrom` number is the original `To` number. It would be best to test this yourself to confirm.